# Why is N*R^2 called an "LM test"?

Tags: econometrics, hypothesis-testing

After [OLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares), one can test the null hypothesis that all coefficients are 0 by calculating $N\cdot R^2$, which is distributed $\chi^2_{k}$ where $k$ is the number of $\beta$ (excluding the constant).

I have seen this called a [Lagrange multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) (LM) test. Why? I'm familiar with the LM test in [MLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation), but I am struggling to see the mathematical connection between these - although it must exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $NR^2$ test is a particular case of an LM test. You can refer to Davidson, R., & MacKinnon, J. G. (1993). Estimation and inference in econometrics, p. 90 for the exact derivation.